# Using arraylist value in another array

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have an arraylist in which I have added values fetched as Json from WebService. In the given activity, I wish to use those values to save it in another array where I use the value to go to a link. I'm getting a `NullPointerException`.

This is how I want to use it:

```
String[] mStrings = {
    "https://fbcdn-sphotos-d-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-frc3/t1.0-9/10245314_566024470177594_4837108279586226729_n.jpg",
    "http://manandhars.com/iexpire/" + arr.get(0) };
```

I'm actually trying to use the json value to load an image. I think I need more of a conceptual suggestion.

Comment: Can you show how you get this array/list `arr`?

Comment: JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);

  try {
  JSONArray cast = jsonObject.getJSONArray("message");
  arr = new ArrayList<Object>();
  for(int i = 0; i < cast.length(); i++)
  {
   JSONObject jsonObj = cast.getJSONObject(i);
   String j= jsonObj.getString("cat_pic");
   arr.add(j);
   System.out.println(arr.get(i));
  }

Comment: can you edit to show more code, specifically the function?im currently thinking arr might be out of scope.

Comment: Please take a look here:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/11208451

Comment: The Thread in your `categoryshow()` method isn't finishing before you're initializing `mStrings`, so `arr` is still null. Declare `mStrings` as a member of the Activity class, set its values at the end of the Thread, and then call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your Adapter.

Comment: Can you give me a more vivid explanation? I'm unable to follow your suggestion.

Comment: @MikeM. I think I did what you told. The value is still null. Can you be more clear about "setting values at the end of the thread"?
This is what I tried. https://gist.github.com/anonymous/11209942
I tried to get the value from that array. Still no luck

Comment: You need to set the values of `mStrings` at the end of the Thread (before the `notifyDataSetChanged()` call) otherwise you'll get the NPE.

Comment: Please take a final look. I think i followed what you told me to.
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/11210789

Answer (score 0):

Using debugger check value of

```
arr
```

and

```
arr.get(0)
```

I am pretty sure, that one of them is *null*.

Comment: I'm getting the value of arr from a function. mStrings is being declared outside. The value of arr.get(0) is not null inside the function. I plan to use the value directly.

Comment: If you're initializing `mStrings` before the function that creates `arr` is called, you will get an NPE. You can probably keep the declaration for `mStrings` where it's at, but move its initialization to after the function for `arr` is called.

Comment: Its hard to say, looking only at this chunk of code. Analyzing **it** I see two possibilities, which were mentioned above.

Comment: @MikeM. - Yes I've initialized it after the function is called. The process actually is tricky. From the function I'm supposed to get the value of arr and that arr was to be used inside mStrings array.  No luck for me. System.out gives me Shutting down Vm. Not even NPE.

Comment: You'll have to provide more code, and a logcat if you've got one.

Comment: here is the code:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/11208451

Logcat: 
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4b20c49ea948dfc047c9